# Has Magneto ever abducted an enemy and held them hostage for any length of time?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, magneto

I am currently working on an X-Men fan fiction story which acts as a modern retelling of the original Stan Lee/Jack Kirby stories. After after having the X-Men defeat Magneto the first time, I was thinking about him and the Brotherhood of Mutants abducting Professor X as a retaliation - but I am worried this may be out of character for Magneto.

Is there any evidence from the X-Men stories of Magneto and the Brotherhood of Mutants abducting an enemy and holding them hostage? Specifically Charles?

Comment: We can see in [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92298/24087) that Magneto has kidnapped his children in the past.

Comment: @Howard8614 Are you asking just about comic books or are you including the movies and other sources as well?

Comment: @JMFB Yes, I am asking about the comic books, movies, and any other sources you can find information from.

Answer (score 3):

Magneto has had no qualms about kidnapping, imprisoning, or killing humans and mutants alike. Magneto has had a prison set up on Genosha (He imprisoned Night Crawler for trespass in Xmen Evolution) and Asteroid M. He tends to be softer on mutants unless he considers them race traitors. Unlike others, he rarely tortures for fun or experiments on them, though there are exceptions (X-Men 1, Senator Kelly). This is true in most mediums and time lines.

That said, Erik has a soft spot for old baldy. A long history of on and off friendship, Magneto would likely never kill or be cruel to Xavier. He protects him, offers him asylum,  hangs out even. if he did kidnap him, it would likely entail disabling his powers somehow but he would phrase it like a guest that's not allowed to leave. He would try to persuade the fool Charles to his side.

The brotherhood wouldn't be so friendly, if not for fear of Magneto.

Comment: The OP would like some evidence.

Comment: @Daft I did cite the xmen movie. As for the rest, it would take citing Charles and Xavier entire multi decade history, both in world and out of universe...

Comment: @cde I personally have to agree with Daft; although I obviously don't expect anyone to cite their entire history, I would like some further detail regarding any instances where Erik held Charles against his will. Also, the Nightcrawler scene you described was from the show Wolverine and the X-Men, not X-Men: Evolution.

Answer (score 0):

He also kidnapped and imprisoned the Red Skull back during the Days of Vengeance series.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site.  Can you provide references and citations for your answer?  Extremely short answers with no references are likely to be deleted.